# No simplifying identities for any single nonzero number under addition.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, universal-algebra

Consider the structure $(\mathbb{R}, +, r)$, where r is a nonzero real number. Are the commutative and associative identities already sufficient to derive all universally valid equations in that structure? Basically, is 0 the only number that behaves in a special manner under addition?

Comment: What do you mean by 'the structure $(\mathbb{R}, +, r)$'?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: The structure (in the sense of first-order logic or universal algebra) over the signature consisting of a binary operation and a constant symbol, where the underlying set is $\mathbb{R}$, the binary operation is $+$, and the constant is $r$.

Comment: This doesn't directly address your question, but it's a way of answering the motivating question "is $0$ the only number that behaves in a special manner under addition?", so it might be worth pointing out. For any nonzero $a$ and $b$ in $\mathbb{R}$, multiplication by $b/a$ is an automorphism of $(\mathbb{R},+)$ sending $a$ to $b$. This shows that all nonzero elements are indistinguishable via formulas in the language of addition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is true.  Suppose $s(x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and $t(x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n)$ are terms in the language of addition such that $s(r,x_1,\dots,x_n)=t(r,x_1,\dots,x_n)$ for all $x_1,\dots,x_n\in\mathbb{R}$.  We can choose $a_1,\dots,a_n\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $r,a_1,\dots,a_n$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$.  Let $F\subset\mathbb{R}$ be the subsemigroup generated by $r,a_1,\dots,a_n$.  The linear independence of $r,a_1,\dots,a_n$ implies that $F$ is freely generated by $r,a_1,\dots,a_n$ as a commutative semigroup (here we use the fact that the free commutative semigroup on a set $\{x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ is the set of formal expressions $\sum m_i x_i$ where $m_i\in\mathbb{N}$ and at least one $m_i$ is nonzero).  Thus the identity $s(r,a_1,\dots,a_n)=t(r,a_1,\dots,a_n)$ implies that actually $s(x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n)=t(x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n)$ whenever $x_0,\dots,x_n$ are elements of any commutative semigroup.